# Excel VBA Keeping Conditional Formatting Formats then removing conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet has a lot of conditional formatting, which is necessary at first to get the colors right, but then after that just causes the spreadsheet to be slow and clunky since it checks the conditional formatting whenever any updates are made.

I'm trying to replace the formatting and then remove the conditional formatting using the following code:

```
Set myRange = mySheet.Range("A1:CJ4000")
myRange.Interior.Color = myRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
myRange.Font.Color = myRange.DisplayFormat.Font.Color
myRange.FormatConditions.Delete
```

It sort of works for the cells that have formatting on them (keeps the back color and font color. But for some reason for other cells, it sets the back color to black (even though there was no fill on them)

Digging around I found that I could do it with this:

```
For Each cell In myRange.Cells
    cell.Interior.Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    cell.Font.Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color
Next cell
```

instead of the general myRange updates in the first code. However with close to a million cells of data, I'm not sure how long that will take to run.

Is this kind of thing not possible to apply to a big range in one go? And I have no choice but to loop through all of the cells one at a time?

Comment: Using `myRange.Interior.Color = xlNone` will clear the interior.color from all you range cells at once

Comment: i don't want to remove the interior color, I want to make it match conditional formatting colors so that I can remove the conditional formatting

Comment: Can you add a last condition that covers all cells ?

Comment: Do the respective conditional formatted cells have **a lot of used colors**? Or only 3, 4? Do all the conditional formatted cells contain rules coloring the font, too, if the interior needs to be colored? I mean are there cases when only interior or only font color is changed?

Comment: I was asking the above clarification due to the possible approach: Iterating between range (a lot of cells) does not need much time. The big problem is **to write something in the range** during the iteration. So, if the number of used colors is reasonable, you can set a variable for each color and build/set `Union` ranges to be changed **at once**. At the end of the code if they will not be huge, or for specific number of rows, which may slow down the code speed considerably after a specific number. I can even post an answer showing how to proceed, but if you consider important answering it.

Comment: @FaneDuru apologies for not answering sooner, didn't actually realise there had been another answer.

there are quite a lot of colours used in the conditional formatting (both forecolor and backcolor)

what do you mean by build/set union ranges? At the moment I'm still having to loop through and apply one cell at a time, which is very time consuming

Comment: Please test the code I pasted and send some feedback. You will understand (I hope) what a `Union` range is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It used two dictionaries, where to place the `Union` ranges of each color (Interior or Font). Since increasing the number of cells in such a `Union` range after a specific limit, the code may tremendously decrease in terms of speed, I added a sequence to change the existing such a range color when it reaches the amount of 500 cells (this is not the maximum able to be handled, a kind of optimum between decreasing the speed by increasing it against time to change the cells color):

```
Sub DeleteFormattCond_KeepColors()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, itCell As Range, rngCol As Range, st_time As Single
  Dim i As Long, DictBack As New Scripting.Dictionary, DictFont As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Const NoIntColor As Long = 16777215, NoFontColor As Long = 0
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last filled row in A:A column
                                                       'you may keep your 4000 if you like it more...
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:CJ" & lastR) 'set the range to be procesed
  
  On Error GoTo ErrorHndl 'to not stop on error and go to the end to reenable the below events
  With Application 'to make increase the code speed:
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
  End With
  
  st_time = Timer
  For Each itCell In rng.cells 'iterate between all cells:
    'process and create Union ranges for DisplayFormat.Interior.Color:
     If itCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> NoIntColor Then 'exclude the empty interior:
        If Not DictBack.Exists(itCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color) Then
            Set DictBack(itCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color) = itCell 'place the first cell of future Union range
                                                                       'for a specific interior color
        Else
            Set rngCol = DictBack(itCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color) 'set rngCol as the existing dictionary range
            addToRange rngCol, itCell 'use this sub to add cells to the Union Range
            If rngCol.cells.count >= 500 Then 'if the Union range exceeds a specific number of cells, it slows down the speed
                rngCol.Interior.Color = itCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color 'drop the necessary colors in the partial range
                Set rngCol = Nothing 'to start a new range
            End If
            Set DictBack(itCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color) = rngCol 'place the Union range back as a dictionary item
        End If
     End If
     
    'process and create Union ranges for DisplayFormat.Font.Color (on the same mechanism as above):
     If itCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color <> NoFontColor Then 'exclude the Automatic black color:
        If Not DictFont.Exists(itCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color) Then
            Set DictFont(itCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color) = itCell
        Else
            Set rngCol = DictFont(itCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color)
            addToRange rngCol, itCell 'use this sub to add cells to the Union Range
            If rngCol.cells.count >= 500 Then
                rngCol.Font.Color = itCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color
                Set rngCol = Nothing
            End If
            Set DictFont(itCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color) = rngCol
        End If
     End If
  Next itCell
  
  'change the interior color for each (remainend) Union Range, at once:
  For i = 0 To DictBack.count - 1
    If Not DictBack.Items()(i) Is Nothing Then
        DictBack.Items()(i).Interior.Color = DictBack.keys()(i)
    End If
  Next i
  
  'change the font color for each (remainend) Union Range, at once:
  For i = 0 To DictFont.count - 1
    If Not DictFont.Items()(i) Is Nothing Then
        DictFont.Items()(i).Font.Color = DictFont.keys()(i)
    End If
  Next i
  
  rng.FormatConditions.Delete 'delete FormatConditions!
 
  MsgBox "Job done in " & Timer - st_time & " seconds..."
ErrorHndl:
 With Application 'reenable the events and calculation type
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
 End With
 If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description & " - " & Err.number
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range) 'the helping Sub to load each cell in the specific Union range
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried commenting each code line which may not be understood. If something still not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

I tested the code on a testing Range ("A2:CJ4001") and processing took about 112 seconds.

Now, I cannot stop myself stating that I hope that you will not come back here after other two weeks...

The code needs a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. The code can be easily changed to use late binding but you will loose in speed, for such a huge range. If difficult to do it, I can post a piece of code to do it automatically.

In fact, nobody knows when you will be back here, so, please copy the next code and run it **before running the above main one**. It would be good to save the workbook after that to keep the reference. It can be extremely helpful in the future, I think:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.vbE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need, or does it take too much time? Or you will be back here after other two weeks...?

Comment: thank you for this, that's really very much appreciated, I will definitely test and let you know how it goes, trying to understand it as well, so taking a bit of time

Comment: @Michael Liew I think, it is enough to make a backup of your workbook, then copy the above code, activate the sheet in discussion and run the code. It will do what you need (in less than two minutes) and confirm it, displaying the consumed time, in seconds. After that you will send some feedback and start understanding the code. I commented all code lines, except ones repeating as meaning. Even so, you may ask for clarification if something still not clear enough... In my opinion, first (most important phase) should not take more than 5 to 10 minutes...

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get it running, and it runs really well.
To be honest I've never used scripting dictionary before, so going to read up on how that's working.
It still took a bit of time (my sheets are just really big) but I used your code and split it up to remove formatting from one column at a time (only about 50% of columns actually have conditional formatting)
And it's running nice and fast now

Removed your 500 filter as well, and just made sure my ranges didn't exceed that size

It's helped me a lot and sped my process up from almost 40 minutes to about 6 minutes

Comment: @Michael Don't you need processing the range you are asked for ("A1:CJ4000")? If so, how big really it is? If "A1:CJ4000", running it for all the range (at once) will take less time, and nothing wrong will happen with the range/workbook. If not, how huge it really is?

Comment: full size of the range is A1 to CJ12000+

out of the columns A to CJ though, less than half actually have conditional formatting, so instead of cycling through all the cells in all the columns, I running it multiple times, just on the sets of columns that have conditional formatting, and it helps with the run time

Comment: because I didn't think of it at the time of asking the question

I appreciate the code you did and it works for my purposes with the little tweaks I've done. I don't understand why you are getting so aggressive and aggro though. Your code worked, I thanked you for it and for some reason you seem upset that I've tweaked your code to my needs